# In Haskell, how to get 0.03, instead of 3.0e-2?

Tags: string, haskell, floating-point, double

Basically the title. I'm trying to display floats in a string, but the result ends up being `"3.0e-2"` (In the example of the float `"0.03"`). How do I get in decimal form in Haskell? Thanks to anyone who answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pretty formatting values of built-in types, use [`printf`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.14/base-4.14.3.0/Text-Printf.html#v:printf):

```
> printf "%f" (0.03 :: Float)
0.03
```

See the linked docs for a full explanation and all possible formatting options.

Comment: See also [`showFFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloat), which is the function that `printf` calls when it sees `%f`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just for clarification: is printf a function that needs to be imported?

Comment: Yes, it does. Check the link.